# Redirect website to www on IIS 10 (Win Server 2019) issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redirect, iis-10

I have website on React which runs on 3000 port. Currently, my website works with `www` and without `www` which leads to duplicate issues by SEO engines. I want to make the website always redirect to `https://www.pess.org.ua`.

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RedirectToWWW" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^pess.org.ua$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.pess.org.ua/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpErrors>
            <remove statusCode="502" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errors/404.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="502" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errors/502.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I enter `http://pess.org.ua`, it redirects to https://www.pess.org.ua:3000/, which adds the 3000 port to the URL and it fails with the following issue:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection [www.pess.org.ua](http://www.pess.org.ua) sent an invalid response.
> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

How to remove this port from URL or redirect without port 3000?

Comment: The `ReverseProxyInboundRule1` rule is run and stops processing. Since that matches all URLs, it will never hit the `RedirectToWWW` rule.

Comment: @HereticMonkey
I removed `ReverseProxyInboundRule1` rule and when I refresh the page I got the following error: 
`403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.` Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I think it leads to 403 error code because this React app runs on 3000 port and it does not know about it at this point.

Comment: No, I don't know why your website is forbidden. Probably has to do with the lack of inbound proxy :). I think you can remove the `stopProcessing="true"` attribute from the `ReverseProxyInboundRule1` node instead of removing it altogether.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It works. But still not all URLs are properly redirect. Please, check out the screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/rb08xZ7/2023-08-02-184058.png
I should add more rules or how to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: I found the issue, it appends: `https://pess.org.ua/ttp://localhost:3000/` when I enter: `https://pess.org.ua/` without `www`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey
So, when I remove `stopProcessing="true"` it appends `ttp://localhost:3000/` to URL. So, the full URL will be: `https://www.pess.org.ua/ttp://localhost:3000/` which is completely wrong. It should be `https://www.pess.org.ua/`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey
I think, my rule `RedirectToWWW` is also wrong: `https://pess.org.ua` leads to `https://www.pess.org.ua/ttp://localhost:3000/`

Where I can get docs how to correctly set rules on `IIS 10`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have fixed this issue by changing action to: `<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.pess.org.ua/" redirectType="Permanent" />` in `RedirectToWWW` rule and setting the `stopProcessing="false"` in `ReverseProxyInboundRule1`.

Additionally, when working on this issue, I would suggest to remove the old cache or use the incognito window, so you can check out the latest changes.

**web.config**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RedirectToWWW" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^pess\.org.ua$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.pess.org.ua/" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
              </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpErrors>
            <remove statusCode="502" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errors/404.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="502" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errors/502.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Now, it redirects to https://www.pess.org.ua. This issue is resolved. Thank you.

Comment: @YurongDai

I can mark it as accepted only in 22 hours: `You can accept your own answer in 22 hours` because it blocks me.